# Python3 Pyserial and Cisco console

Tags: python, pyserial, cisco

I have reused some python code to configure a cisco switch via serial console. This works great with Python 2.7 version but since moving to Python 3.x it stopped working correctly. I understand that now there's a need to encode the string in order to avoid Pyserial to throw exception errors due to change made in Python 3

"Python 3.0 uses the concepts of text and (binary) data instead of Unicode strings and 8-bit strings. All text is Unicode; however encoded Unicode is represented as binary data. The type used to hold text is str, the type used to hold data is bytes."

However, it seems as the cisco switch is not recognizing the data that its been sent.

Once again it works great with Python 2.7 but since the changes on Python 3, I am unable to get script to work.

```
def readSerial(self, console):

    dataBytes = console.inWaiting()
    if dataBytes:
        return console.read(dataBytes)

    else:
        return ""
def checkStatus(self, console):

    console.write(str("\r\n\r\n").encode())
    time.sleep(1)

    prompt = self.readSerial(console)
    if str.encode('[yes/no]:') in prompt:
        console.write(str('no \r\n').encode()) # switch is not recognizing the encoded string sent via serial COM4 

        return True
    elif '#' in prompt:
        return True
    elif '>' in prompt:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Using console.read() method, output shows the string 'no \r\n' in bytes but switch still ask initial setup configuration question :

Would you like to enter the initial configuration dialog? [yes/no]: \r\n% Please answer 'yes' or 'no'

Which, should not be the case. It should initialize user EXEC mode ">"

Does anyone has any experience in this scenario ? Any learned lessons that you can share ?

Answer (score 0):

In our project we do

```
console.write(bytes(input_str, 'ISO-8859-1'))
```

I believe you will have to find out what encoding your device expects. The list of supported ones can be found at  https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: Thanks Lianne. I think the problem is that Cisco CLI is expecting a string value and does not know how to decode the bytes value its receiving. Or at least for the initial configuration dialog question. It does not take any sent value to it. However, if question is manually answer script is able to send CLI commands using encode() method.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to an oversight on the code.

console.write(str('no \r\n').encode()) # This command had an additional white space and that is the reason Cisco switch was not taking it.

Thanks